# Stringify function for generic container in C++

Tags: c++, string, templates

How create a generic stringify function for a generic container also for nested container e.g. `map<string,vector<list<int>>>`?
This is my attempt but it doesn't work.

```
template<class T>
string stringify(const T& c) {
    int length = c.size();
    string str = "[";
    int i=0;
    for (; i <= length-2; i++) {
        str += stringfy(c[i]) + ", ";
    }
    str += c[i] + "]";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your attempt work?

Comment: Sorry for a maybe naive comment, but what would be `c[i]` if `c`is a `map<string,vector<list<int>>>` ?

Comment: @user253751 Oups - My bad.

Comment: In general you can't do this.  You need to make a `stringify` that works for iterable types, then you need a stringify that works for fundemental types, and then you need a `stringify` for each custom type (`std::pair`, you own classes).

Comment: With what @NathanOliver mentioned, one can get close by using `std::ostringstream` and a number of templates. If every type is streamable, it's feasable, but it won't be a "works in all cases" solution.

Comment: @Ted I would like to see a code of your idea

Comment: @Damien You're right in that case the type of 'i' and the key of map mismatch

Comment: @asv Ok - I'll put something together when I get to a computer (4-8 hours).

Comment: See this for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers

Comment: Because this is a template, you may have difficulty encoding the template instantiation type. Therefore you might find it easier to explicitly make a wrapping function for each type of T, then printing out the encoded value of the type, within the string, followed by the string encoding, this will allow you to reread the data back afterwards into a map. You can still call the templated function within the typed implimented wrapper functions.

Comment: @asv I think I don't need to take it further, right? The "Pretty-print C++ STL containers" link kind of did it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried here: https://repl.it/repls/UnderstatedShortCgi but it doesn't work

Comment: @asv I  remembered that I made a promise ... then beer happened, but I came to deliver ... and you let me off the hook. Brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doable but mostly pointless as you would typically know what kind of data you have to process.

I managed to come up with something like this. It will work for every type that is iterable with for-each loop or a tuple, or has overloaded `operator<<`. You can do it without C++20 features but it will be a total SFINAE mess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
concept InterableRange = requires (T a) {
    std::begin(a);
    std::end(a);
};

template <typename T>
concept TupleLikeType = requires (T a) {
    std::tuple_size<T>();
};

template<TupleLikeType T>
string stringify(const T& c);

template<class T>
string stringify(const T& c);

template<InterableRange T>
string stringify(const T& c) {
    string str = "[ ";
    auto size = std::size(c);
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (const auto& elem : c) {
        str += stringify(elem);
        if(i++ < size - 1)
            str += ", ";
    }
    str += " ]";
    return str;
}

template<TupleLikeType T>
string stringify(const T& c) {
    string str = "[ ";
    auto size = std::tuple_size<T>();
    std::size_t i = 0;

    std::stringstream input;   
    auto insert = [&input, size, &i](const auto& data) {
        input << stringify(data);
        if(i++ < size - 1)
        {
            input.put(',');
            input.put(' ');
        }
    };
    std::apply([&insert](const auto&... args){
        (insert(args), ...);
    }, c);

    str += input.str();
    str += " ]";
    return str;
}

template<class T>
string stringify(const T& c) {
    std::stringstream input;   
    input << c;
    return input.str();
}


int main() {
    map<string,vector<list<int>>> m {
        { "1", {{1,2}, {3, 4}}},
        { "2", {{10,20}, {30, 40}}}
    };
    cout << stringify(m);
}
```

It will print

```
[ [ [ 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ] ], [ [ 2 ], [ [ 10, 20 ], [ 30, 40 ] ] ] ]
```

Comment: I tried here: https://repl.it/repls/AvariciousVagueDriverwrapper and it doesn't work.

Comment: @asv Because it uses clang7 and you need a C++20 compiler that supports concepts: https://godbolt.org/z/VVHbzh

Unfortunately C++20 support is not very good yet as it was only recently finalized.

Answer (score 3):

I did a C++17 solution, the SFINAE is still bearable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>


// Forward declarations so we can have arbitrary interactions
template<class Container, class Iter = decltype(cbegin(std::declval<Container>()))> // SFINAE to get only containers
std::string stringify(const Container&c); 
template<class T1, class T2>
std::string stringify(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p); // Can we get this into the tuple case?
template<class ...Ts>
std::string stringify(std::tuple<Ts...> &t);

template<class T, class = decltype(std::declval<std::stringstream>() << std::declval<T>())>
std::string stringify(T t) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << t;

    return s.str();
}

template<class ...Ts>
std::string stringify(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) {
    const auto string_comma = [] (const auto & arg) { return stringify(arg) + ", "; };
    // This prints a , too much but I am too lazy to fix that
    return '(' + std::apply([&] (const auto& ...args) { return (string_comma(args) + ...); }, t) + ')'; 
}

template<class T1, class T2>
std::string stringify(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) {
    return '(' + stringify(p.first) + ", " + stringify(p.second) + ')';
}

template<class Iter> 
std::string stringify(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    std::string ret{'['};
    for(; begin != end;) {
        ret += stringify(*begin);
        if(++begin != end) {
            ret += ", ";
        }
    }
    ret+=']';
    return ret;
}

template<class Container, class Iter>
std::string stringify(const Container&c) {
    return stringify(cbegin(c), cend(c));
}

int main () {
    std::set<std::vector<std::map<int, char>>> v {{{{1, 'A'}, {2, 'E'}}, {{2, 'B'}}}, {{{2, 'C'}}, {{3, 'D'}}}};
    std::tuple tup {1.0, "HELLO WORLD", std::pair{67, 42}};

    std::cout << stringify(begin(v), end(v)) << '\n';
    std::cout << stringify(tup) << '\n';

}
```

Comment: I tried here https://repl.it/repls/FlimsyLongtermStruct and it doesn't work.

Comment: @asv You are trying to compile it with C++14, but it is C++17 code. To make it C++14 compatible, one would have to do the stringification of tuples in a template-recursive way, since C++14 does not have `std::apply` and cannot use parameter pack fold expressions.